# hi i have one problem on terminal when send update or install app my terminal have some error

Tags: .desktop

```
mxgun@mxgun-master:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for mxgun: 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done     
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:6
```

Comment: Duplicate lines are because a user on your system with `sudo` rights has added the same entry twice (or it existed once, and was added a second time).  Those messages contain the files and line numbers on those files where entries exist, making them easy to correct.  (remove a single entry or comment it out by adding a "#" at start of the line)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicate lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: It may be helpful when answering questions, especially those asked by new users, to provide instructions on how to achieve what you are suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `apt-get` instead of `apt`:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
```

Also try using `upgrade` instead of `update`:

```bsh
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The `update` command downloads the package files, but doesn't actually apply them. You must use `upgrade` after. The upgrade command then applies the downloaded update packages. Make sure to do both.

Comment: `update` doesn't download packages--it downloads information about which ones are available, in what versions, from where. `upgrade` downloads and installs packages (when available in newer versions than installed). It's true people should usually perform the `update` action followed by the `upgrade` action. However, that won't help in this case, because this question is about a problem that occurs when performing the `update` action. The first recommendation is also unlikely to help, unfortunately, as the problem is in `sources.list`, which both `apt` and `apt-get` use.